# React - History.replace in try/catch create an error

Tags: reactjs, try-catch, react-hooks, browser-history

Good morning

I have a handleSubmit function when I validate my form, everything works, my api sends me errors if there are any, and the registration is done, only, impossible to redirect if everything works... The History.replace systematically create an error that I do not understand, especially since all my .replace everywhere on my site works.

My handleSubmit function :

```
    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const apiErrors = {};
        if(user.password !== user.passwordConfirm) {
            apiErrors.passwordConfirm = "mdpError"
            setErrors(apiErrors)
            return;
        }
        try {
            await usersApi.register(user)
            setErrors({})
            history.replace("/")
        } catch (error) {
            const { violations } = error.response.data;
            if (violations) {
                violations.forEach(violation => {
                    apiErrors[violation.propertyPath] = violation.message
                })
                setErrors(apiErrors);
            }
        }
    }
```

The console displays this error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

I'm recovering nicely in the parameters of my {history} component...

If anyone has an idea, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is because your error object doesn't have the response attribute it will have a message i.e error.message in place of error.response.

```
 try {
            await usersApi.register(user)
            setErrors({})
            history.replace("/")
        } catch (error) {
            // try printing your error here and check
            console.log(error) //-> check if it has response attribute??
            const { violations } = error.response.data;
            if (violations) {
                violations.forEach(violation => {
                    apiErrors[violation.propertyPath] = violation.message
                })
                setErrors(apiErrors);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error is : TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined. o.O

Comment: @Minos ``` The console displays this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined ``` this is what you wrote in the question.

Did you try props.history?

Comment: I think I've found the solution, 
I imported {withRouter}, and I exported the components with the router: 
export default withRouter(register}...

Comment: @Minos yes you can access it by props.history or {history} = props